# Solution to no ultimately trusted keys found

Tags: ppa, add-apt-repository

I tried installing tlp and Ubuntu tweak on my new Ubuntu (previously I had the same Ubuntu, but reinstalled it).

When adding their sources, I got the error no ultimately trusted keys found. In the previous installation I did not get these errors.

Answer (score 4):

This is a PPA problem; it's all about broken PPA's. All you need to do is fix them. If you want to know more about why it has happened,[read here](http://trog.qgl.org/20091030/troubleshooting-gnupg-gpg-no-ultimately-trusted-keys-found).

To fix the issue , open your terminal and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install launchpad-getkeys
```

Then launch the application with `sudo`

```
sudo launchpad-getkeys
```

Credit to [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/automatically-import-all-missing.html) & [trog.qgl.org](http://trog.qgl.org/20091030/troubleshooting-gnupg-gpg-no-ultimately-trusted-keys-found)

Comment: You also can use a program called YPPA manager, it can do it for you.  https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/tweaking-ubuntu/yppa-manager

Comment: "my@my-Pc:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gnome-panel is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source"THis comes up

Comment: yes its due to the PPA Problems.

Comment: this is after I used the launchpad

Comment: @Hassan disable the other PPA in your software sources for temporarily and update the cache again.